# Inatgrating Laravel Socialite facebook login with basic auth

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, laravel-5.3

Already I have integrated the Laravel default Auth in my application now I want to integrate social logins with it.

Here is the work flow

1.get user details(social_id,name,email,profile_pic) from socialite

2.check the user existence with email ,if its exists execute `auth::login`,
  otherwise create a new record in users table and redirect to profile.

When a user **remove email-id during Facebook auth Approval page**  I will get

`$user-getEmail()` as null so in this case above workflow is not applicable since everything is depend on user email so how can I handle this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since everything is depend on user email

Well that's the problem.  You need to be able to handle Facebook users without email addresses.  So on login, instead of checking for users' existence based on email, check:

- If the provider is Facebook, check based on `User->getId()`
- Otherwise, check based on email

See [this tutorial](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html) for some further code samples.

Comment: Actually we can't avoid email id we bcz everything based upon this

Comment: OK, either don't make everything based on this, or don't use facebook, or just return a login error if a facebook user is not providing their email address.  What other possibility could there possibly be?

Comment: Go with the third option in your comment